# Using one custom taxonomy.php for two custom taxonomies?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have registered 2 custom taxonomies, 'allergy' and 'gmc_allergy' which are of post type 'gmc_recipe'.

I have a taxonomy-allergy.php and when I go to blah.com?allergy=test then it correctly lists all posts that have 'allergy' assigned to them.

It also correctly lists any 'gmc_allergy' as long as there are some 'allergy' in the list too (due to my custom logic in the taxonomy-allergy.php).

How can I make blah.com?allergy=test return results for 'gmc_allergy' when there are 0 results for the taxonomy 'allergy' but there are results for 'gmc_allergy'?

Currently I get a 404 error which is understandable since my logic for showing 'gmc_allergy' is within the taxonmy-allergy.php and that never gets executed as there are 0 results for 'allergy'.

I have created:

```
function gmc_pre_get_posts($query)
{
  if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query())
  {
    if (is_tax())
    {
       $query->set('taxonomy', array('gmc_allergy', 'allergy')); //So now it will also include gmc_allergy where before it was only checking for allergy which was in the url?
       $query->set('post_type', array('post', 'page', 'gmc_recipe');
    }
  }
  return $query;
}
```

But this still gives me a 404, am I on the right path? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well... `taxonomy-allergy.php` should display the allergy _taxonomy_. That is how the template hierarchy works. `taxonomy-gmc_allergy.php` should display the gmc_allergy _taxonomy_, if you had that file on your system. But you are talking about ___Post Types___, so I am unclear what you have happening. Please try to clarify.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I've completely rewritten my question.

Comment: your question is still confusing. taxonomy queries are for individual *terms* within a taxonomy, not whole *taxonomies* like a post type archive.

Comment: My two taxonomies lookup the same term id. I'm trying to share the same file for both taxonomies. 'gmc_allergy' maps to a custom post type of 'gmc_recipe' and 'allergy' maps to a 'post'.